# I have a div and button in

Tags: javascript

I have a div and a button in it both having onclick event.  When clicked on button the div click event is firing and button click is not working.  When clicked second time the button click is firing.  What is the solution for this?  I have to use only javascript please. I m spending time from last few days on the same issue. Please help me.

Comment: You know you could probably include your code, right?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please could you add some examples of your code.  Also please read this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What about posting some code? Since you are asking "why my code is not working" you should also post a minimal and verifiable example of your code. Adding a jsfiddle would be perfect"

Comment: please add the code you are using, better to make sample fiddle demo for your problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

i am not an expert but i found a solution

```
var myFn = function(){
var blockClick = document.getElementById('block-click'),
    btnClick = document.getElementById('btn-click'),
    self = this;

    self.actionMethod = function (){

        blockClick.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event){               
            event.preventDefault();

            if(event.target.id === 'btn-click'){
                return;
            }

            console.log(this)
        })
        btnClick.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event){
            console.log(this)

        })

    }
    actionMethod();
 }
myFn();
```